# Is a field with archimedean absolute value with compact unit sphere complete?

Tags: field-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

By the unit sphere of a valued field $(K,|\cdot|)$ I mean $\{x\in K:|x|=1\}$.

We know that if the unit closed ball $\{x\in K:|x|\le 1\}$ of a valued field $K$ with nontrivial absolute value is compact, then $K$ is a local field: for every $x\in K$, the set $\{x'\in K:|x'-x|\le 1\}$, being homeomorphic to the unit closed ball, is a compact neighborhood of $x$. From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4649260/for-a-nonarchimedean-field-k-does-the-group-of-units-of-mathcalo-k-being) one learns that the compactness of the unit sphere implies the compactness of the unit closed ball for a nonarchimedean field. As a result,  if the unit sphere of nonarchimedean field with nontrivial absolute value is compact, then is a local field.

I'm interested in the archimedean case: if $|\cdot|$ is an archimedean absolute value on $K$ with compact unit sphere, what can be said about $K$? Must it be complete, in which case it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ by one of the two Ostrowski's theorems?

**Edit:** Every archimedean field can be embedded into $\mathbb{C}$, so we can suppose that $K\subset\mathbb{C}$. I have been able to show that $\{x\in K:|x|=1\}$ is compact if and only if it is equal to either $\{x\in \mathbb{C}:|x|=1\}$ or $\{\pm 1\}$ (see Note below). Of course, $\{x\in K:|x|=1\}=\{x\in \mathbb{C}:|x|=1\}$ if and only if $K$ contains the field generated by $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\{x\in \mathbb{C}:|x|=1\}$. So the question becomes **how to determine the subfields $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy $\{x\in K:|x|=1\}=\{\pm 1\}$**. Apart from subfields of $\mathbb{R}$, fields of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{D})$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\omega^2\sqrt[3]{D})$ are also examples, where $\omega=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}{\rm i}}{2}$ is a primitive 3rd root of unity and $D\in\mathbb{Q}^+$ is not a cube.

**Note:** A subgroup of the group of unit circle is either discrete or dense, with the proof being similar to the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ case. If $\{x\in K:|x|=1\}$ is compact, it is either the whole unit circle or discrete. In the latter case there is a maximum $N\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that $\exp\left(\dfrac{\pi\mathrm{i}}{N}\right)\in K$. If $N\ge 2$, then $\dfrac{r+\exp\left(\dfrac{\pi\mathrm{i}}{N}\right)}{r+\exp\left(\dfrac{\pi\mathrm{i}(N-1)}{N}\right)}\in K$ would have modulus $1$ and argument $2\arctan\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{\pi}{N}}{r+\cos\dfrac{\pi}{N}}\in \left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{N}\right)$ whenever $r\in(1,+\infty)\cap K$, which is a contradiction.

**Edit 2:** It should be clarified that, the question now is **to find the subfields $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$, such that $\{x\in K:|x|=1\}=\{\pm 1\}$.** Of course we are interested only in those that are not contained in $\mathbb{R}$.

The condition of $K$ is equivalent to: **for every $x\in K\setminus(\mathbb{R}\cup\mathrm{i}\mathbb{R})$, one has $\overline{x}\notin K$.** "$\Longleftarrow$": suppose that $x=\exp(\mathrm{i}\theta)\in K$, then $\overline{x}=x^{-1}\in K$, so $x\in\{1,\mathrm{i},-1,\mathrm{-i}\}$, and $x=\pm\mathrm{i}$ is clearly impossible (for example, $K$ contains $a+b\mathrm{i}$ and its conjugate whenever $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, $ab\neq 0$). $\Longrightarrow$": if $x\in K\setminus(\mathbb{R}\cup\mathrm{i}\mathbb{R})$, then $\frac{\overline{x}}{x}$ has norm $1$, but is not equal to $\pm 1$.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Wow, the example is so easy! Silly me! If you don't mind, I'm going to wait to see if there are any examples apart from the proper subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ :)

Comment: All archimedian fields are isomorphic to subfield of $\mathbb R$ :)

Comment: @mihaild Sorry, did you mean subfield of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The two examples you exhibit might not be subfields of $\mathbb R$ the way they are written, but they are isomorphic to subfields of $\mathbb R$. So the natural conjecture is that the fields you are looking for are exactly the fields which have an embedding into $\mathbb R$ (e.g. for number fields, the ones that are *not* [totally imaginary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_imaginary_number_field)).

Comment: I changed the title and wording to avoid confusion with archimedean orders. -- Do you mind sharing your proof on why the "unit sphere" is either $\pm1$ or the full complex unit circle?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Done.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, just remarks. I call $U =\{x \in \mathbb C : \lvert x \rvert =1\}$ the complex unit circle.

1. Annoyingly, and contrary to what I naively believed in earlier comments, the property you look for is **not invariant under field isomorphism**, i.e. there can be subfields $K \simeq L$ of $\mathbb C$ such that $K\cap U = \{\pm1\}$ but $L \cap U$ is dense in $U$. For an algebraic example, take $K = \mathbb Q(s)$ with $s$ a [Salem number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem_number), and let $L=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ one of the non-real roots of the minimal polynomial of $s$.
2. This applies "even more so" to transcendental extensions, as the rational function field $K=\mathbb Q(T)$ can be embedded into $\mathbb R$, but of course we can alternatively send $T$ to any transcendental element of the unit circle in $\mathbb C$.
3. On the positive side, the argument you outline generalizes to the following characterization.

**Proposition**: Let $K \subset \mathbb C$ be a subfield. Then $K \cap U$ is dense in $U$ if and only if $K$ contains a non-real field $K_0 \not \subset \mathbb R$ which is stable under the complex conjugation $\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C, x \mapsto \bar x$.

**Proof**: If $K \cap U$ is dense in $U$, take any $u \in U \setminus \{\pm1\}$; since $\bar u = u^{-1}$, $K_0 := \mathbb Q(u) \subset \mathbb C$ will do. Conversely, by assumptions $K_0$ and hence $K$ contains some pair $\bar x \neq x$, so it also contains all
$$u_r := \dfrac{r+x}{r+\bar x} $$
for all $r\in \mathbb Q$, and these generate a dense subgroup of $U$.

How helpful this characterization is, is up to debate. At least it gives us some sufficient criteria, which *are* invariant under field isomorphisms:

**Corollary**: If $K$ is a field which contains a *[CM field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CM-field)*, or a non-real *Galois* extension of $\mathbb Q$, then every embedding $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb C$ contains a dense subgroup of the unit circle.

(This applies e.g. to all $p$-adic fields which, according to axiom of choice, can be embedded into the complex numbers, and which (regardless of choice) contain e.g. many CM fields.)

4. In earlier comments, I had speculated that the number fields $K$ with dense $K\cap U$ might be exactly the totally complex ("totally imaginary") ones. This is false. The examples in comment 1 (cf. also the answers to [Are all algebraic integers with absolute value 1 roots of unity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4323/96384) as well as K. Conrad's https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/numbersoncircle.pdf) are fields $K$ with dense $K\cap U$ that have ("also") real embeddings; on the other hand, e.g. $K := \mathbb Q(X)/(X^4+2)$ is totally complex but neither of its embeddings into $\mathbb C$ is stable under conjugation (if they were, they would be Galois). These examples also show that the sufficient criterion in the corollary above is not necessary.
5. In the short note [1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C432985D26C49A9D6B16AF10548E022F/S1446788700011460a.pdf/note_on_the_characterization_of_cmfields.pdf), the above proposition is the main step to prove a characterization of CM-fields which singles them out from the more general fields we are after here (and which distinguishes them from the fields generated by Salem numbers or similar). Galois-theoretically, Galois CM fields are the ones among the above where complex conjugation is (not just contained in but) *central* in their Galois group, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/q/203012/27465. Also, it follows from https://mathoverflow.net/q/131475/27465 that CM fields are exactly the totally complex fields for which $\iota(K)$ is stable under conjugation for *all* embeddings $\iota: K \hookrightarrow \mathbb C$.

[1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C432985D26C49A9D6B16AF10548E022F/S1446788700011460a.pdf/note_on_the_characterization_of_cmfields.pdf) *Blanksby, P. E.; Loxton, J. H.*, [A note on the characterization of CM-fields](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C432985D26C49A9D6B16AF10548E022F/S1446788700011460a.pdf/note_on_the_characterization_of_cmfields.pdf), J. Aust. Math. Soc., Ser. A 26, 26-30 (1978). [ZBL0413.12002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0413.12002).Blanksby, P., & Loxton, J. (1978). A note on the characterization of CM-fields. *Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society,* *26*(1), 26-30. doi:10.1017/S1446788700011460

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration! :)